# SPARK code for sql case statement and row_number equivalent

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data set like below

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop fs -cat /user/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt
Eid1,EName1,EDept1,100
Eid2,EName2,EDept1,102
Eid3,EName3,EDept1,101
Eid4,EName4,EDept2,110
Eid5,EName5,EDept2,121
Eid6,EName6,EDept3,99
```

I want to generate the output as below using spark code

```
Eid1,EName1,IT,102,1
Eid2,EName2,IT,101,2
Eid3,EName3,IT,100,3
Eid4,EName4,ComSc,121,1
Eid5,EName5,ComSc,110,2
Eid6,EName6,Mech,99,1
```

which is equivalent of the below SQL

Select emp_id, emp_name, case when emp_dept='EDept1' then 'IT' when emp_dept='EDept2' then 'ComSc' when emp_dept='EDept3' then 'Mech' end dept_name, emp_sal, row_number() over (partition by emp_dept order by emp_sal desc) as rn from emp

Can someone suggest how should I get that in spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RDD.zipWithIndex, then convert it to a DataFrame, then use min() and join to get the results you want.

Like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// SORT BY added as per comment request
val test = sc.textFile("/user/hadoop/test.txt")
  .sortBy(_.split(",")(2)).sortBy(_.split(",")(3).toInt)

// Table to hold the dept name lookups
val deptDF = 
  sc.parallelize(Array(("EDept1", "IT"),("EDept2", "ComSc"),("EDept3", "Mech")))
  .toDF("deptCode", "dept")

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("col1", StringType, false),
  StructField("col2", StringType, false),
  StructField("col3", StringType, false),
  StructField("col4", StringType, false),
  StructField("col5", LongType, false))
)

// join to deptDF added as per comment
val testDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  test.zipWithIndex.map(tuple => Row.fromSeq(tuple._1.split(",") ++ Array(tuple._2))),
  schema
)
.join(deptDF, $"col3" === $"deptCode")
.select($"col1", $"col2", $"dept" as "col3", $"col4", $"col5")
.orderBy($"col5")

testDF.show

col1 col2   col3  col4 col5
Eid1 EName1 IT    100  0
Eid3 EName3 IT    101  1
Eid2 EName2 IT    102  2
Eid4 EName4 ComSc 110  3
Eid5 EName5 ComSc 121  4
Eid6 EName6 Mech  99   5

val result = testDF.join(
  testDF.groupBy($"col3").agg($"col3" as "g_col3", min($"col5") as "start"),
  $"col3" === $"g_col3"
)
.select($"col1", $"col2", $"col3", $"col4", $"col5" - $"start" + 1 as "index")

result.show

col1 col2   col3   col4 index
Eid4 EName4 ComSc 110  1
Eid5 EName5 ComSc 121  2
Eid6 EName6 Mech  99   1
Eid1 EName1 IT    100  1
Eid3 EName3 IT    101  2
Eid2 EName2 IT    102  3
```

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. But in the result col4 is not sorted in desc order. Could you please sort that as well.

Comment: Also David the case part is not handled in your solution

Comment: Missed the sort. And do you have a full list of department names?

Comment: No I don't. Actually this has handled with a case statement in sql (means if EDept1 then hard coding as IT etc.). Can we write any conditional statement in spark like this?

Comment: Getting error : might be braces missing                                              scala> val test = sc.textFile("/user/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt").sortBy(_.split(",")(2).sortBy(_.split(",")(3).toInt
     | )
     | )
<console>:27: error: value split is not a member of Char
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val test = sc.textFile("/user/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt").sortBy(_.split(",")(2).sortBy(_.split(",")(3).toInt

Comment: In you sort it is done in ASC order. If it would be in desc order then what change is required here?

Comment: DESC sort is achieved just applying a -1 in the second sort                        val test = sc.textFile("/user/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt").sortBy(_.split(",")(2)).sortBy(_.split(",")(3).toInt * -1)

Comment: David thnx for your reply - could you please just help me understand the part "map(tuple => Row.fromSeq(tuple._1.split(",") ++ Array(tuple._2)))" what is purpose of fromSeq and tuple._2

Comment: So i missed a couple of parentheses -- why you got the error. Also, you seem to have taken out the underscores. Should be `_.split` not just `.split`. As for DESC, add 'false' as a second argument to sortBy -- `.sortBy(_.split(",")(2) ,false)` -- that works with strings and Ints.

Comment: .zipWithIndex creates a tuple. The left side of the tuple contains the original data, the right side of the tuple contains the index. In Scala, the two parts of the tuple are retrieved with <val name>._1 and <val name>._2. Now to create a DataFrame you first need an RDD of Row objects, but textFile only returns an RDD of one string per line. So my map takes the tuple created with zipWithIndex, and splits it into an Array, performs a union with the single element Array for the index so that it is all in one Array, then passes this whole Array to Row.fromSeq, which creates the individual DF Rows

Comment: Thnx David for all of your reply. One last question how to save the data frame result in a file. I have used "result.save("/user/hduser/out")" -- it saved around 200 parquet files in that directory, those are not readable. Can I save it in text format?

Comment: Try `testDF.rdd.saveAsTextFile(...)` though I never use it so you are on your own.

Comment: Hi David - I have some more queries as part of the above example. So I have raised one more question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391075/spark-how-to-implement-case-else-part-and-where-like-and-between". Request you to please help me in this