# SPARK : How to implement CASE ELSE part and WHERE LIKE and BETWEEN

Tags: apache-spark

I have data like below

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop fs -cat /user/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt
Eid1,EName1,EDept1,100
Eid2,EmpNm2,EDept1,102
Eid3,EName3,EDept1,101
Eid4,EName4,EDept2,110
Eid5,EName5,EDept2,121
Eid6,EName6,EDept4,99
```

I want to get the output like below

```
Eid1,EName1,IT,100
Eid3,EName3,IT,101
Eid5,EName4,ComSc,110
Eid6,EName6,Other,99
```

Now in form of SQL I can write

```
Select emp_id, emp_name, case when emp_dept='EDept1' then 'IT' 
when emp_dept='EDept2' then 'ComSc' else 'Other' end dept_name, emp_sal from emp 
Where emp_name like 'EName%' And emp_sal between 90 and 120
```

My question is 1. how to implement ELSE part of CASE Statement 2. How to implement LIKE part of the where clause 3. How to implement between part of the where clause.

I can't use sqlContext.sql as the sql also contain analytical function and analytical function is not supported in spark-sql as of now.

Comment: Hi Koushik. When you ask something in stackoverflow, please use the "code sample" button (the one that looks like `{}`) instead of the "code snippet". Snippets are meant to be used only with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, which are runnable in the browser.

Comment: ok..Next time onwards I will use code sample option

Comment: I had a cut-and-paste typo in my answer, edited just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can create a UDF like this:

```
val deptUdf = udf[String,String]( dept =>
  dept match {
    case "EDept1" => "IT"
    case "EDept2" => "ComSc"
    case _ => "Other"
  }
)
```

Once you do that you can use it in a select statement. Assuming you had a DataFrame with your dept name in the "deptCode" column, you could do:

```
myDf.select(deptUdf($"deptCode") as "deptName")
```

For the second and third parts, there is a `like` function you can use in a filter, and you can implement `between` using `and`:

```
myDf.filter($"emp_name" like "EName%" and $"emp_sal" >= 90 and $"emp_sal" <= 120)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using sqlContext.sql I'd go ahead and use the HiveContext - the HiveContext doesn't require a hive installation but it does expose many more hive UDFs. If that doesn't work for you, you could also write a UDF to convert the department and register it on the sqlContext.

Comment: I can create a data frame like `val deptDF = sc.parallelize(Array(("EDept1", "IT"),("EDept2", "ComSc"))).toDF("deptCode", "dept")` and join it with the other data frame. But not sure how to handle the else part of the case i.e. when nothing is matching print Other